# Radio.Group and Radio.Button components don't type-check

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I recently migrated a working JavaScript/React project to Typescript. Wherever, in React components I use `antd` components the code fails to type-check.
E.g. I have things like the following:

```
import { Radio, Button } from 'antd'; 
 
...
<Radio.Group ...>
      <Radio.Button ...>a button</Radio.Button>

</Radio.Group>
```

... and I get type errors like the following:

```
TS2339: Property 'Group' does not exist on type 'ForwardRefExoticComponent<RadioProps & RefAttributes<unknown>>'.
TS2339: Property 'Button' does not exist on type 'ForwardRefExoticComponent<RadioProps & RefAttributes<unknown>>'
```

The [antd typesecript](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-in-typescript) section indicates that the library is typescript-ready and even says that you don't have to `npm i --D @types/antd`. I tried both with and without `@types/antd` explicitly installed but that seems to make no difference.

I am using:

- antd@4.3.3
- typescript@3.9.5
- react@16.12.0

Comment: Check this out, it might help: https://codesandbox.io/s/7x2jd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `moduleResolution` to `"node"` in the `compilerOptions` of my `tsconfig.json` fixed that.